# what is the difference between user-defined conversion and user-defined operator?

Tags: c++

In the context of operator overloading, what is the difference between user-defined conversion and user-defined operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"User-defined conversions allow you to specify object conversions with constructors or with conversion functions. User-defined conversions are implicitly used in addition to standard conversions for conversion of initializers, functions arguments, function return values, expression operands, expressions controlling iteration, selection statements, and explicit type conversions."

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr383.htm

I'm not sure that user-defined operators are available (technically) in C++, but operators can be overloaded.

http://www.cs.caltech.edu/courses/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html

Comment: There are no user-defined operators in `C++`.

Comment: @Mahesh: Except for user-defined type conversion operators.

Answer (score 4):

A user-defined conversion is either:

- A constructor in the destination type which can be called with a single parameter of the source type (more arguments can exist if they have default values)

or

- A non-static member function of the source type with the name `operator DESTTYPE()`

As you can see, the second option uses the `operator` keyword just as is used when overloading the traditional operators.

(Note: All of this is formally described in section `[class.conv]` of the C++ standard.)

Answer (score 1):

In `C++`, there is no concept of user-defined operators that can be overloadable. Only existing operators, with an exception of few( **.**, **.***, **::**, **?:**, **sizeof** ), can be overloaded.

Comment: No, that's not a user-defined conversion.  That's a compiler-defined upcast.  User-defined conversions have to operate on a value of class type, not pointers (ok, either source or destination can be a pointer, but not both).

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Since compiler is acting up on user-defined types, cann't we consider them as user-defined type conversions.

Comment: @Mahesh: Your example was converting from a (raw) pointer type to another (raw) pointer type.  (Raw) pointers are not user-defined types.  Conversion of user-defined types is not automatically a user-defined conversion, it is called a user-defined conversion only if it runs user-provided code to do the conversion.

Comment: @Ben Voigt - Like when I use const_cast operator etc., am I right?

Comment: @Mahesh: Of the C++ template-style casts, only `static_cast` invokes user-defined conversions.  The others (`dynamic_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, and `const_cast`) are compiler-provided conversions.